# Is it good to send a new RabbitMQ message from consumer to the same queue?

Tags: web-services, architecture, rabbitmq

I do mailings via rabbitmq: I send a mailing list from the main application, the consumer reads it and sends it.
A broadcast may consist of different messages, which must be sent in the correct order.
In fact, a mailing list is a list of messages: `[message_1, message_2, message_3, message_4]`

Some of the messages can be sent and at some point the third-party service stops accepting requests.
I will describe the process of the consumer:

1. I take out the message from queue which contains distribution.
2. Sending: 1 part > 2 part
3. An error occurs. It remains to send 3 part > 4 part.
4. Acknowledge the original message from the queue.
5. Put a new one at the beginning of the same queue: `[message 3, message 4]`.

**Question 1**: Is it good to send a new message (from consumer) created from parts of an old one to the same queue?

**Question 2**: Is it a good solution?
Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you posted loses a message if the handler process crashes between steps 4 and 5. So you have to switch the order of steps 4 and 5. But as soon as you do that you have to deal with the duplication of messages. If for some reason (like a bug) ack fails for a large percentage of messages you can end up with the same broadcast repeated multiple times in the queue. So if you want to avoid duplicated messages you have to use some external persistence to perform deduping. Also, RabbitMQ doesn't guarantee that messages are delivered in the same order. So you can end up in a situation where two messages for the same address are delivered out of order. So deduping should be on the level of individual parts, not entire messages.

> Question 2: Is it a good solution? Are there any other solutions?

Consider using an orchestrator like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) which eliminates most of the consistency problems I described.

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 really need to be changed, thanks. I guarantee the delivery of only the 1st message using the database (I didn’t write about it in the question).